# Errors in installation of sparsesuite

Tags: makefile

ON installing sparsesuite I am getting following errors.Can someone explain me?

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:541: recipe for target '/home/sangeeta/SuiteSparse/lib/libcholmod.so.3.0.11' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/sangeeta/SuiteSparse/lib/libcholmod.so.3.0.11] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeeta/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD/Lib'
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'library' failed
make[2]: *** [library] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeeta/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD/Lib'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sangeeta/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'go' failed
make: *** [go] Error 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. What OS are you using? From where have you downloaded the `sparsesuit`? What steps have you followed to install the **__sparsesuit__**? The error that you have posted is not helpful.

Comment: What you postet is only the error **summary** ... you'll find the **actual** error somewhere above that.

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow ! This appears to be a linker error (missing libraries or object files probably) but your quote only shows the end of it and misses the important part. We'll only be able to help you if we see the whole error, or if you spot the linker error itself.